# sublime text 2 build system for multimarkdown under windows 7

Tags: windows-7, build, sublimetext2, multimarkdown

To process a .md file in multimarkdown, I've written a build system file:

```
{
"shell":true,
"working_dir" : "${file_path}",
"cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\MultiMarkdown\\multimarkdown.exe", "-b", "$file"],
"cmd": "${file/\\.md/\\.html/}"
}
```

While the .html file opens in my browser correctly (if it exists), MultiMarkdown isn't called - since the .html file isn't generated by CTRL+B/F7.

However, in cmd this works:

```
multimarkdown -b test.md
```

I guess my PATH variable is fine, but Sublime can't access multimarkdown.

I've tried this as well:

```
"cmd": ["multimarkdown", "-b", "$file"],
```

and

```
"cmd": ["multimarkdown -b", "$file"],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a duplicate `cmd` key. Since Sublime Text uses [JSON](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) for its build systems, it probably overwrites the first key with the second one.

Thus, remove the second key and your first one will execute:

```
{
"shell":true,
"working_dir" : "${file_path}",
"cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\MultiMarkdown\\multimarkdown.exe", "-b", "$file"],
}
```